# Getting Hardware Info script trouble

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, windows-7, hardware

With help from the Internet I've managed to write a basic PowerShell script that collects hardware info and exports it to a CSV file. It gathers:

- Hostname
- CPU
- NumberOfCores
- GPU
- RAM

My script still needs to get HDD info (capacity, freespace, id), IPv4 address and MAC.

```
$Name = hostname
$Motherboard = Get-WmiObject Win32_BaseBoard
$CPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor
$GPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController
$RAM = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem

$To_File = new-object PSObject -property @{
    'Name' = $Name
    'Motherboard' = $Motherboard.Product
    'CPU' = $CPU.Name
    'Cores' = $CPU.NumberOfCores
    'GPU' = $GPU.Name
    'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($RAM.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)
}

$To_File | Select-Object Name, Motherboard, CPU, Cores, GPU, RAM |
    Export-Csv G:\$Name.csv
```

Earlier, I also had a line for getting IP and MAC, but it wasn't working universally. It looked like this:

```
$IP = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where ($_.DNSDomain -eq 'lan')
$MAC = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where ($_.DNSDomain -eq 'lan')
```

Then I would just use in `$To_File` object `'IP' = $IP.IPAddress` and `'MAC' = $MAC.MacAddress`

It wasn't good since not all the adapters were named "lan".

For HDD I wrote:

```
$Disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3

$DiskInfo = foreach ($zm in $Disk) {
    'ID: ' + $zm.DeviceID
    'Capacity: ' + "{0:N2}" -f ($zm.Size/1GB)
    'Free Space: ' + "{0:N2}" -f ($zm.FreeSpace/1GB)
}
```

Since some computers had more than one HDD but I didn't know how I can join these two things together so I could have all that info above and HDD's in one file.

I can't do all that stuff remotely, so the script is on a USB drive and I go to each computer and run it by myself. I still have to do around 20 machines.

I'd also like to know how I can add new rows to an existing CSV file because having 15 CSVs and 'merging' them together is painfull.

Comment: That's several questions at once. Please focus on one problem at a time, show what you have tried to solve the problem, show your desired and actual output, and explain what isn't working as expected (include all errors you're getting).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-append` command with your `export-csv` command in order add new rows with the existing rows. Your command would look like

```
$To_File | Select-Object Name, Motherboard, CPU, Cores, GPU, RAM |
Export-Csv G:\$Name.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

[Powershell - Export-CSV and Append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220239/powershell-export-csv-and-append) link will be helpful to you I guess.