# String Length different when using ISE or Powershell.exe

Tags: string, powershell

I have written a small user Interface with PowerShell in order to create checksums comfortable. At the moment I see a difference between using the ISE and the powershell itself.

When running the PowerShell script within the ISE I get perfect results.
This is the code I am using (Just a snippet):

```
$aaa = (Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA512 -Path $str_filepath |
       Select-Object -Property hash |
       Format-Table -HideTableHeaders |
       Out-string).TrimEnd().TrimStart()
```

So I create a checksum (SHA512) from a file. These are the results for one file as example:

Running the script in ISE:

```
0518E6DF62AB7B8D7A238039262C7A0E9F1F457D514EDE2BB8B3F4719340EF4B61053EC85ED30D07688B447DBC756F3A7455D7E0C84C7BCF62A8884E4715C8A0
```

Running the script in PowerShell:

```
0518E6DF62AB7B8D7A238039262C7A0E9F1F457D514EDE2BB8B3F4719340EF4B61053EC85ED30D07688B447DBC756F3A7455D7E0C84C7BCF62A8...
```

As you can see the string is shortend when using PowerShell. More confusing is that the shortening is not consistent. At home on my Windows 7 machine the string is even shorter then on my Windows 8.1 System at work. I know that there are some differences between ISE and PowerShell when running scripts regarding to styles. But shorter strings... Hmm.

So now the question. Does anyone of you have expierenced that difference between ISE and Powershell regarding to String length limitations? And if so. Does have anyone an answer for me how I can script it that there will be no different string results?

Comment: The window length might interfere with the string legth visibility in the console. Better take the value and output to a file

Comment: The string is just shortened for display purposes because it doesn't fit the console. Try `(Get-FileHash ...).Hash` to simply access the property directly, without all the `Select-Object` and `Format-Table` hoopla. This should not be subject to further formatting. Conversely, if you want formatting that's easier to interact with, `Out-GridView` is hard to beat.

Comment: OK Thank you. I need to say that I see the difference in an CSV sheet. I do export the result to a csv sheet. On the screen the string is not shortend. I have tried that. So to make that clear. I see the different results in a CSV file. I fill the csv sheet by using the echo command.

Comment: this is the code to Export the strings to the csv file "echo "$str_filepath`t$str_filename`t$str_filesize_in_bytes`t$str_file_creationtime`t$str_file_lastwritetime`t$str_checksum_md5`t$str_checksum_sha1`t$str_checksum_sha256`t$str_checksum_sha384`t$str_checksum_sha512" >> $form_status_label_csv_logfile_folder.Text
        "

Comment: You could use `Export-Csv -Append`, that's what it's there for. (Requires PowerShell 3 or later, but [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9220239/4137916).)

Comment: I got it. You were right guys. It is the buffer size for window width regarding to the powershell.exe. This was causing the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `Format-*` cmdlets if you need to process your data further. Those cmdlets are *only* for displaying data to a user. Instead expand the `Hash` property of the object `Get-FileHash` returns, either like this:

```
$str_checksum_sha512 = (Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA512 -Path $str_filepath).Hash
```

or like this:

```
$str_checksum_sha512 = Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA512 -Path $str_filepath |
                       Select-Object -Expand Hash
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. I have used your method 1 and it is working perfectly for me. When I was creating the very long scriptline with remove header and trim I was sure that this cannot be best practice. As I am quite new in Powershell this was new for me and very very helpful. So thank you very much! Your help is very very appreciated. :)