# Exporting Membership groups for users from input file

Tags: powershell

I have this script that reads samaccountnames from a file and outputs the name of the user with its membership information. However, the output file only shows the last record. It seems that my code is overwriting the previous record. What am I missing? Thank you so much.

```
ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content -Path C:\MyScripts\UsersInput.csv)) 
{
    $username = Get-ADUser –Identity $user -Properties * 
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select $username.DisplayName, name | 
    export-csv "C:\MyScripts\UsersAndTheirADGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation  
}
```

Comment: put  export-csv outside the loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - Export-CSV and Append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220239/powershell-export-csv-and-append)

Comment: Why are you reading in a CSV with `Get-Content` and not `Import-Csv`? Show us a part of that file `C:\MyScripts\UsersInput.csv` (sanitized ofcourse). The first two or three lines will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Export-Csv has an -append parameter, so you could use that.  ie it would append to the csv file with every iteration of the loop.  You would need to make sure the file didn't exist before you start the loop or it would just get bigger and bigger each time you ran the code.

Another way it to add the items to an object and then export that at the end. ie $username += Get-ADUser......

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a CSV file using `Get-Content`. This lets me think the file is simply a list of user SamAccountNames, each on a separate line. No headings.
Something like this perhaps:

```
jdoe
jsmith
```

If that is the case, read the input file like this:

```
$users = Get-Content -Path 'C:\MyScripts\UsersInput.csv'
```

To get an array of user SAMAccountnames.

**If** however it is a proper CSV file with headers, looking something like this:

```
"SamAccountName","Email","More","Stuff"
"jdoe","john.doe@yourdomain.com","blah","blah"
"jsmith","jane.smith@yourdomain.com","blah","blah"
```

Then you should use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to get the entries as objects and obtain an array of SamAccountNames from that:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\MyScripts\UsersInput.csv' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
```

Once you have that array, loop through it and get the group membership info for each user

*Untested*

```
$result = foreach ($accountName in $users) {
    Get-ADUser –Identity $accountName -Properties DistinguishedName, DisplayName |
        Select-Object @{Name = 'User'; Expression = {$_.DisplayName}},  
                      @{Name = 'Groups'; Expression = { ( $_ | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name) -join ', '}}
}
$result | Export-Csv "C:\MyScripts\UsersAndTheirADGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed overwriting the code `ForEach` user. You included `Export-Csv` in the `ForEach`. Instead export the whole array that `ForEach` creates:

```
ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content -Path C:\MyScripts\UsersInput.csv)) 
{
    $username = Get-ADUser –Identity $user -Properties * 
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select $username.DisplayName, name
} | export-csv "C:\MyScripts\UsersAndTheirADGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```