# Powershell - Export-CSV outside loop only last line is printed/exported

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to adjust this code to export all lines outside `foreach` loop:

This works fine (inside loop):

```
 $vms = Get-VM | Where { $_.State –eq ‘Running’ } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 

 foreach($vm in $vms) {

    # Get network interface details
    $out = Get-VMNetworkAdapter -vmname $vm | select VMName, MacAddress, IPAddresses

    $vm_name = $out.VMName | Get-Unique
     $ip = ($out.IPAddresses | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | ? {$_ -notmatch ':'}
     }) -join " "
    # If more than 1 MAC , put it in same row separated by space (00:15:5D:58:12:5E 00:15:5D:58:12:5F )

    $mac = ($out.MacAddress | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":")
}) -join ' '

$results = @()      

$comp = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VM NAME" -Value $vm_name
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "IP ADDRESS" -Value $ip
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MAC ADDRESS" -Value $mac
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HYPER-V HOST" -Value $comp


$results += $obj

Write-Output $results

$results| Export-Csv -Path "c:\1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -append 
}
```

However, when i move `$results| Export-Csv -Path "c:\1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -append` outside loop,
only one (last) line is saved to CSV

Inside loop, `$results` variable contains all lines, when i move this variable outside loop `write-host $results` only one (last) line is printed

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220239/powershell-export-csv-and-append

Comment: Put the last line of your code outside the `foreach` loop. Since you already have everything in `$results`, you can directly export the variable to a csv. Remove the `-append` parameter.

Comment: i did it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, your code can be condensed quite a bit. Many of your steps are not necessary:

```
$results = Get-VM | Where State –eq Running | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'VM NAME'      = $_.VMName
        'IP ADDRESS'   = ($_.IPAddresses -notmatch ':') -join ' '
        'MAC ADDRESS'  = ($_.MacAddress -replace '(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)','$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:') -join ' '
        'HYPER-V HOST' = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "c:\1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Notes:

- You can pipe the VMs that `Get-VM` returns directly into `Get-VMNetworkAdapter`
- If you filter on a single property you don't need a script block for `Where-Object`. `Where State -eq Running` is a bit easier to write and read than `Where { $_.State -eq 'Running' }`.
- `$_.IPAddresses -notmatch ':'` Operators like `-notmatch` work on arrays. `'a','b','0','c' -notmatch '\d'` will return `'a','b','c'`.
- The same goes for `-replace`. `'a0','b1','c2' -replace '\d',''` will return return `'a','b','c'`. No `foreach` loops necessary at all.
- `$env:COMPUTERNAME` should be faster than using WMI to get the computer name
- Any object you create in a script block (like the `ForEach-Object {...}` script block) that you do *not* assign to a variable will be in the script block's output. This is why `$results = ... | ForEach-Object {...}` works. There is no need to explicitly create arrays with `@()` and add values to them.
- Casting a hash table to `[pscustomobject]` is much easier than using `Add-Member`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

moved `$results` variable outside loop (make it "global")

```
$vms = Get-VM | Where { $_.State –eq ‘Running’ } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 

$results = @()

 foreach($vm in $vms) {

    # Get network interface details

    $out = Get-VMNetworkAdapter -vmname $vm | select VMName, MacAddress, IPAddresses

    # Remove duplicate VM names

    $vm_name = $out.VMName | Get-Unique


    # In case more than 1 IP, put it in same row separated by space (192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2)


    $ip = ($out.IPAddresses | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | ? {$_ -notmatch ':'}

    }) -join " "

    # If more than 1 MAC , put it in same row separated by space (00:15:5D:58:12:5E 00:15:5D:58:12:5F )

    $mac = ($out.MacAddress | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":")
}) -join ' '



$comp = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VM NAME" -Value $vm_name
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "IP ADDRESS" -Value $ip
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MAC ADDRESS" -Value $mac
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HYPER-V HOST" -Value $comp


 $results += $obj


}
$results| Export-Csv -Path "c:\1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```